# throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[ Error

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to debug my program, it shows me debug.dart page underlining "throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>["
What could be the problem?

I'm creating a simple nogin auth page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to look further up the call stack to see what code is triggering that.